# how to find the shortest distance between two nodes that pass at least one of the compulsory nodes?

Tags: graph, distance, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a bi-directed weighted graph with about 5000 nodes
and i have a list of "important" nodes (100 or so). Given a start node and an end node, how do I find the shortest distance between this two nodes that pass at least 1 of the "important" nodes. Note there are no negative edges. I implemented dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest distance given two nodes. And the only way i know how to solve this problem would be to go through the list of important nodes, finding the distance from start -> importantNode#1 -> end for all important nodes then taking the minimum. Is there a faster way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely correct, what you need is to apply Dijkstra lesser number of times.
This problem can easily be solved by applying Dijkstra just two times.

- Apply Dijkstra with *start* as source. Store the distances in array **fromS**.
- Apply Dijkstra one more time. This time take *end* as source. Store the distances in array  **toE** .
  Since your graph is undirected shortest distance from *end* node to every other node is same as shortest distance from every other node to *end* node. (That's the trick).
- Find the required shortest distance.

  ```
  For node in importantNodes :
    ans = min ( fromS [node] + toE[node] , ans)
  return   ans
  ```